# Swift QLPreviewController Navigation Bar and BarButton Item Color Change

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to change QLPreviewController default navigation bar background color and bar button item color change based on my app theme. I used below code but It is not working.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9003542662, green: 0.417613821, blue: 0.147166098, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: What is a `QLPreviewController` is it a class created by you?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontrollerdelegate @Let's_Create